# "Thanks to" - is it a preposition or a conjunction?

Tags: prepositions, usage

> 1. **Thanks to** this treatment, her condition has improved.
> 2. The railway system is in chaos, **thanks to** the government's incompetence.

Both these sentences are from [macmillandictionary.com](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/thanks-to).

- Is *thanks to* used as *a preposition* in the above sentences?
- Why the *comma* is used in the sentences?
- Is *thanks to* ever used as a conjunction?

Comment: From [Quick&Dirty Tips:](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/because-as-a-preposition) - *in Standard English, the word “because” can be used two ways. One of them is to introduce a clause, as in “Aardvark was late because he was waiting for the repairman to show up.” Used this way, “because” is a **subordinating conjunction**. The other is to team up with “of” to form what's called a **compound preposition***. And syntactically, the use of ***thanks to*** here corresponds exactly to ***because of***, which can always replace it - so it too must be a compound preposition.

Comment: (As in *“Aardvark was late **because of / thanks to** heavy traffic”*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I checked Wiktionary and it says that "thanks to" is a preposition.
2. If a sentence starts with a prepositional phrase, you have to put a comma after it.
3. From what I've seen, the only verbs that can come after "thanks to" are the ones that end in "-ing". *However*, I'm not sure if they are regular verbs or gerunds.

For example

a. "Thanks to you slaying the dragon, the kingdom is safe."

b. "Thanks to your slaying of the dragon, the kingdom is safe."

In the second example, "slaying" is a gerund(because of the possessive "your") but I'm not sure about the first example.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you have a citation (with a reference link) to substantiate it's a preposition? The second  sentence in question doesn't begin with a prepositional phrase; still there is a comma in it.

Comment: 1. [Here's a link](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thanks_to). 2. The comma in the second sentence isn't actually *necessary*. "The railway system is in chaos thanks to the government's incompetence." is perfectly acceptable.